# Why the wind spinners blades spin at the same speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

It was a windy day, and I saw a beautiful double wind spinner. I took a slow-mo of it and saw both blades spin at the same speed in opposite directions.

I didn't expect them to spin at the same speed. Was it a coincidence, or will it always go at the same speed?

https://youtube.com/shorts/Lvhyze7gbxI?feature=share

Comment: Due to stroboscopic effects, what you filmed may not be what you think. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect).

Comment: @josephh no man, the rotation speed here is not that fast, the slow-mo is real

Comment: But you took the footage with a digital camera. Did you read the link?